# How are the same items generated with slightly different attributes?

Tags: software-engineering

Consider games like Destiny.  How do they generate weapons that have the same skins and names, but different attributes?  Two people can have the same weapon or armor piece, but have different attributes on these pieces based on luck or drop rate etc.  How is this accomplished programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's pretty easy if you view every single weapon got by player as an instance of pre-defined weapon model.
each instance can have their own data like attack power or weight. They will share material for efficiency, but logically they're single instance since created, you can even use single material for single weapon.

As a side note, game like Destiny often use adjectives to generate variety. It use the **prototype pattern**. 
Imagine you have defined a common sword, and how the game can generate a fire sword with no definition? You can treat **fire** adjective as a **decorator**. When you access the weapon attack, it will come from fire decorator, which will first get normal sword power and then add the fire power.

Comment: Thanks ZenWu, your description was exactly what I was looking for.  Time to research prototype pattern :D

Answer (score 1):

- Create some sort of data structure to hold different attribute types.
- Create some sort of luck formula that fits your game and chooses
  attributes from above mentioned data structure
- Assign values to said attributes based on the same luck formula or another formula or just plain randomness.
- profit ?

Answer (score 0):

To add another example, especially after ZenWu's anwer, I would like to refer to World of Warcraft. Since the last expansion they have a similiar approch to crafted gear where you have basic prototypes as you may call them like [these Demonsteel Gauntlets](http://www.wowhead.com/item=123912/demonsteel-gauntlets). In the item tooltip you will notice that there are only the mainstat and some stamina but no secondary stats. These gauntlest do exist in various versions like [these Demonsteel Gauntlets of the Peerless](http://www.wowhead.com/item=123912/demonsteel-gauntlets&bonus=689:1683). The developers have specific affixes to their item names which are different versions of the same item. These different item versions can be explored using the link to the right of "Item Version" where you can change both the item level, the affix, tertiary stats or sockets. While doing so you might notice the url change as well since the bonus variable holds a bunch of id representing specific additions.

In this small example one could possibly think about a `DemonsteelGauntlet` class which just holds a variable based on an enumeration of all the particular types to deduce what version you have at hand (no pun intended). Of course this is only feasible if you have a limited amout of possible variants of the same item. If you are going to randomize more than just a dozen affixes you might want to attach some further meta-information to those particular items. Some kind of reasonable datastructure which holds those stats or some other special information where you can add those.